# Unit testing a Spring POJO with injected EJBs

Tags: java, spring, ejb-3.0, junit4

I am not sure if this is possible but I am trying to come up with a Spring Junit test against a Spring POJO that has injected EJBs in it. when I run the test, I always get a nullpointerexception on the injected EJB in my test POJO. The problem is that the methods of the POJO don't expect the EJB interfaces as method parameters, so they need to be available when my POJO is loaded thru the spring context. I am using Spring 2.5 and EJB 3.0 on a weblogic 10.3 container. I did add `<context:annotation-config/>` to my spring context file.

For example, I have an EJB that is being injected into a POJO similar to the below code and I would like to do a unit test against MySpringPojo methods. I have seen that no matter how I try to test, my EJB doesnt get injected into the POJO for the test to run. Can anyone please suggest how we could test this kind of a scenario ? Any help with a code snippet would be awesome...

```
public class MySpringPojo {
   @EJB
   private GreetingManager greeting;

   public String greetUser(String name) {
      return greeting.generateGreeting(name);
   }
}

@Remote
public interface GreetingManager {
   public String generateGreeting(String name);
}

@Stateless
public class GreetingManagerBean implements GreetingManager {
   public String generateGreeting(String name) {
       return "Hello" + name;
   }
}
```

-Sonu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you still need an answer but I wrote up an article to have EJBs injected into Spring and test the POJO in a Weblogic container. You can read up about it [here](http://pillutla.dyndns.org/wordpress/?p=45).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry Mario your princess is in another castle :( Link is dead. To avoid this kind of answers add an extract, I know it's easiest to post the link but as you may have seen it could be gone :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you are running JUnit in non-Java EE environment, so real EJBs won't be available.
2. What you need to do is add stubbed implementation of GreetingManager, say GreetingManagerStub, and test your business logic.